# Why does the main OS menu bar disappear when I am in Safari?

Tags: safari, menu-bar

I am running OS X 10.8.2 on a MacBook Pro with a 27" Cinema Display. Just this week I noticed that when I switch over to Safari the Main Menu Bar (not the Safari menu bar) disappears. I have checked to make sure that I am not in full screen mode. I also checked the desktop settings and don't see anything that would turn that off. The menu bar shows when I am in any application other than Safari. Again, this is the main menu bar, not the safari menu bar.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Weird. Maybe log out and back in. That should solve the problem.

Comment: I have the same problem when watching Netflix in full-screen mode.  The only fix I have found is to restart Safari.

Comment: Actually, sometimes the menu bar comes back after waiting a while.  It seems the issue may be related to Silverlight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strange I am having same issue when I log in. But changing desktops a few times solves the issue. So I think its a graphic bug

Comment: I rebooted and it went away, but I think your assessment it probably correct here. It happened after I changed my desktop image.

Answer (score 2):

I have also experienced this. What I found out was that it was as a result of dual display when I connected my MAC to my TV and used Safari in full-screen mode on the TV. I experienced Menu Bar disappear when I launch Safari after disconnecting from my TV.
What I did to resolve the issue was to re-connect to TV and quit Safari while it was in full-screen mode (on the TV), and then relaunch the application.

Answer (score 0):

You may be in full screen mode. Place your curser in the upper right hand corner and when the menu bar appears click the exit full screen (blue box with the arrows inside that point to each other)

Comment: The person asking the question said: "I have checked to make sure that I am not in full screen mode. "

Answer (score 0):

My college-age son solved this problem (easily) for me.  Click anywhere on your desktop to induce the Finder menu bar to appear.  Then click anywhere on your Safari window and the Safari menu bar will appear.  Works every time - only 2 clicks!

Comment: This does not address the issue in my case.  Once I click back on Safari, the menu vanishes again.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why this happens but I understand exactly what you mean.

It isn't an issue of having inadvertently hid the toolbar like a fool.  I think it may be the thing that asks you if you would like the window to remain in full screen after you minimize a full screen video in Netflix, Amazon or whatever video you're watching that requires silverlight.

I found a solution:
On the control bar where the Safari icon is located, completely close out of Safari.  When you open it back up, the toolbar reappears and stays whilst browsing.

[image]
quit down here and reopen

It took some digging to find that answer but it seems to be working.  The quick fix did mention that it is a temporary thing so I assume it develops again after a fullscreen video is played in silverlight with that weird prompt.